# How to use sed to replace a filename in text file

Tags: linux, sed

I have a file:
`dynamicclaspath.cfg`

```
VENDOR_JAR=/clear-as-1-d/apps/sterling/jar/struts/2_5_18/1_0_0/log4j-core-2.10.0.jar
VENDOR_JAR=/clear-as-1-d/apps/sterling/jar/log4j/2_17_1/log4j-core-2.10.0.jar
```

I want to replace any occurrence of `log4j-core*` with `log4j-core-2.17.1.jar`

I tried this but I know I'm missing a regex:

```
sed -i '/^log4j-core/ s/[-]* /log4j-core-2.17.1.jar/'
```

Comment: With your shown samples please try like: `sed 's/log4j-core-.*\.jar/log4j-core-2.17.1.jar/g'   Input_file` once. You need to match till `.jar`, assuming you have only 1 entry in your samples this should work.

Comment: `sed 's/log4j-core.*/log4j-core-2.17.1.jar/' dynamicclaspath.cfg`?

Comment: OR if you are looking in the last level of path about jar files then try something like: `sed -E 's/(^.*\/)log4j-core-.*/\1log4j-core-2.17.1.jar/' Input_file`

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples please try following `sed` program. Using `-E` option with `sed` to enable ERE(extended regular expressions) with it. In main program using substitute option to perform substitution. Using `sed`'s capability to use regex and store matched values into temp buffer(capturing groups). Matching till last occurrence of `/` and then matching log4j-core till jar at last of value. While substituting it with 1st capturing group value(till last occurrence of `/`) followed by new value of log4j as per OP's requirement.

```
sed -E 's/(^.*\/)log4j-core-.*\.jar$/\1log4j-core-2.17.1.jar/' Input_file
```

Comment: You could save a few characters by expanding the capture group :-) `sed -E 's/(^.*\/log4j-core-).*\.jar$/\12.17.1.jar/' file`

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/(log4j-core-)[0-9.]+/\12.17.1./' input_file
VENDOR_JAR=/clear-as-1-d/apps/sterling/jar/struts/2_5_18/1_0_0/log4j-core-2.17.1.jar
VENDOR_JAR=/clear-as-1-d/apps/sterling/jar/log4j/2_17_1/log4j-core-2.17.1.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on possible other contents in your input file how specific the search pattern must be.

```
sed 's/log4j-core-.*\.jar/log4j-core-2.17.1.jar/' inputfile
```

or

```
sed 's/log4j-core-[0-9.]*\.jar/log4j-core-2.17.1.jar/' inputfile
```

or (if `log4j-core*.jar` is always the last part of the line)

```
sed 's/log4j-core.*/log4j-core-2.17.1.jar/' inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i s'@2.10.0.jar$@2.17.1.jar@'g file
```

That seems to work.